# Why my React app can't fetch my Express API?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fetch, port, http-status-code-400

I created a server in Node and Express, everything runs smoothly when I make requests from Postman or my browser.

However when I try to fetch I get the following error

```
main.chunk.js:35 GET http://localhost:5000/api/users 400 (Bad Request)
```

I have already tried adding cors to all my routes, however the problem is the same

This is my server code

```
require("dotenv").config();
require("./database");

const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const cors = require('cors');
const helmet = require("helmet");

// inits
const app = express();

// settings
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4000);

// middlewares
app.use(cors());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.json()); // to req and res json files through an API

// routes
app.use(require("./routes"));
app.use("/api/transactions", require("./routes/transactions.routes"));
app.use("/api/auth", require("./routes/auth.routes"));
app.use("/api/users", require("./routes/users.routes"));

// starting the server
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port: ${app.get('port')}`);
});
```

This is my fetch code in React with hooks

```
useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            //let url = "https://jopy.herokuapp.com/api/users";
            let url = "http://localhost:5000/api/users";

            try {
                const data = await fetch(url);
                console.log(data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        };

        fetchData();
    }, []);
```

Do you have any idea about?

Comment: What does process.env.PORT contain?

Answer (score 0):

You set api server port as 4000

> app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4000);

But you are trying to fetch api from port 5000